# Xamarin XAML DataTrigger Animations

Tags: xaml, animation, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have defined an Animation as a resource that works when called via an EventTrigger like this:

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <animations:StoryBoard x:Key="FadeInLogo" Target="{x:Reference Logo}">
            <animations:FadeToAnimation Opacity="1" Duration="700" />
        </animations:StoryBoard>
    </ResourceDictionary>   
   <ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then

```
<ContentPage.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger Event="Appearing">
        <triggers:BeginAnimation  Animation="{StaticResource FadeInLogo}" />
```

***However***

When I try to call that same animation via a DataTrigger, the compiler says that a Property of TargetType is needed to create a DataTrigger object???

```
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOkToLogin}" Value="true" >
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions >
            <triggers:BeginAnimation  Animation="{StaticResource FadeInLogo}"></triggers:BeginAnimation>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Trigger must (re)define the TargetType:

```
  <ContentPage.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="ContentPage" Binding="{Binding IsOkToLogin}" Value="true" >
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions >
            <triggers:BeginAnimation  Animation="{StaticResource FadeInLogo}"></triggers:BeginAnimation>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
  </ContentPage.Triggers>
```

Comment: What namespace does "triggers:" refer to?

Comment: It was just a copy paste of the question not directly linked to the error. Ask @BahaiResearch.com